# Derivatives of overscript variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

If we have an expression with terms of some variable and terms of the same variable with some overscript, the differentiation of this expression does not entirely function.

---

[image]

---

The problem is that Mathematica does not recognize $\stackrel{\text{batman}}{x}$ and $x$ as two intrinsically different variables. Anyone know of some fix to this?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/193

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Try the [notation package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/guide/NotationPackage.html) and the Symbolize command. (but what you are trying to do is very confusing. Why not use normal symbols?)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Notation package and Symbolize command, worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to have a separate variable format as Overscript[x, batman]

```
Format[xbat] := Overscript[x, batman];

expr = xbat^2 + x^2
```

[image]

```
D[expr, xbat]
```

[image]

```
D[expr, x]
```

> 2 x